# Python Postgres Testcontainer is stuck in CI Pipeline

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker

I use testcontainers python to create a db for my tests. On mine and other local machines it ist working, but not in the Gitlab CI pipeline. I know that the container is starting, so it shouldt be a dind issue, because I can get the logs. But I just cant connect to it. I tried "localhost", the standard config and the gateway- or bridge ip. But it is every time stuck in "Waiting to be ready...", the underlying error is "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out   Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 49269?". My Code to start the container is this.
`with PostgresContainer(image="postgres:14.7", dbname="postgres", port=5432) as postgres: print(f"Postgres started on port {postgres.get_connection_url()}") yield create_engine(postgres.get_connection_url(), echo=False)`

I tried "localhost", the standard config and the gateway- or bridge ip. As well as showing all the available logs. But it didn't get more insights. The problem shouldnt relate to the gitlab runners, because other (C#) projects do use testcontainers as well.

Comment: you can just run a postgres container as a service 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/postgres.html

Comment: Thank you, but  I already know that alternative and this is only my fallback solution. :)